# Centos Authconf Error

Tags: linux, authentication, centos, openldap

I am currently trying to the authentication and authorisation on centos with the following command:

`authconfig --enableforcelegacy --update`
And it throws me following message, since I am pretty new to linux I currently a bit struggeling to find out what I have to do:

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/sbin/authconfig", line 1071, in <module>
sys.exit(module.run())
File "/sbin/authconfig", line 640, in run
self.parseOptions()
File "/sbin/authconfig", line 128, in parseOptions
help=_("enable shadowed passwords by default"))
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/gettext.py", line 571, in lgettext
return ldgettext(_current_domain, message)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/gettext.py", line 543, in ldgettext
return t.lgettext(message)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/gettext.py", line 368, in lgettext
return tmsg.encode(locale.getpreferredencoding())
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf6' in position
12: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Did anyone face any similar issue like this before? Could you please share with me how you were able to resolve is? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: I have to agree with @shelter here - this should probably be on SuperUser or Unix SE.

Comment: Apology for the mistake and thanks for highlighting. I will do the necessary steps to move it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it with the following command:

```
export LC_ALL=C
```

I found it from a similar case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14547631/python-locale-error-unsupported-locale-setting